# How to best do a multi string find?

Tags: d

I'm having some issue doing a fast multi string find.

This script stalls infinitely during compilation until ram explodes

It freezes at the find() call

https://dpaste.dzfl.pl/6b1b6400c4b4

While this script works fine and compiles and runs

https://dpaste.dzfl.pl/40c4a8724872

Before I would just do matchAll with a list of regex, but that would be cripplingly slow for large lists. I also tried with one ctRegex!("keyword1|keyword2|...") with matchAll but it was prohibitively slow.

Using multiple canFind() seems fastest, but appears to scan through the string multiple times for every call.

Comment: Why are you using `AliasSeq` like an array of strings?

Comment: If you want it really fast, take a look at [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). This is however beyond the scope of standard libraries of programming languages, D included, so you will probably have to implement it yourself.

Comment: There is boyerMooreFinder in [std.algorithm.searching](https://dlang.org/library/std/algorithm/searching.html) for single string searches which may take sublinear time in terms of text size.

Comment: @John-Smith Find returns the offset of the argument that was matched. If you have a long list of arguments you'd have to hard code every offset when you check response. Easier to reference the offset to an array.